# MSYS angleproject build - patch issues

Tags: mingw, msys2, msys

Working on my project and need to build angleproject package. Had to install `pacman -S patch` and I stuck.
After I go to `makepkg-mingw` MSYS asking questions as below - what is correct answer?
[image]

Comment: The correct solution is to understand what the patch was meant to do. If the `angle.gyp` file just moved to a different location, you need to use the `-p` option or modify the paths in the patch file manually. If the file doesn't exist or is heavily modified, you need to create a new patch. There's also a possibility that the patch is no longer needed, e.g. because it was incorporated into upstream repository; in that case, just remove it and the corresponding lines in `PKGBUILD`.

Comment: This is a good source for dealing with makepkg and MSYS2< https://www.msys2.org/wiki/Creating-Packages/>, but you still need programming and porting skills.